# An Alghorithm for draw 2*3 = 6 subplot in one page (plot) for lots of figures with python

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I've coded in python to drawing plots from excel file. In my case, the first column (= X) is fix and other columns (= Y) are changing to drawing. Code is here (and make pdf file):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import xlrd

def rasm(x, y, ylable):  #plot
    plt.clf()
    plt.bar(x,y) #some extra codes for briefing are deleted.
    return (plt.draw())

#save file as pdf
pdf = PdfPages(output_path)

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(input_address)
sh1 = wb.sheet_by_name(u'Sheet1')

#axes of chart
x = sh1.col_values(0)  # column 0 from sheet 1
ylable = x[0]

ab=sh1.row_values(0)

for i in range(1, len(ab)):   #draw any fig in one page, x axis is constant, y axis are change
    y = sh1.col_values(i)  # column i
    fig = rasm(x, y, ylable)    
    pdf.savefig(fig)
pdf.close()
```

Now I want to use an algorithm that draw 6 figures per page by using subplot (in python, i.e matplotlib). And continue drawing next 6 subplots and do it until end of records (in excel). in the other words, plot 6 figures in one page and then go to next page. Because figures are a lot, I had to do it. In this time, I don't have an idea ;). But algorithm can follow:

```
until reords not end:
   for i in range(1,6):
      subplot my figs from excel
      go next page and do it for next 6 columns (7:12, 13:18, ...).
```

Thanks.

Comment: Every six sets of data make a new Figure with six subplots then save the figure. https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html#subplots-axes-and-figures, https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-usage-py

Comment: i.e. I use sets of data like tuples? I cannot got it.

Comment: Anytime `i` is divisable by six make a new figure.